# Выпадающее меню на всю высоту

Tags: html

Хочу сделать выпадающее меню на всю высоту экрана. Сделал через Height: 100vh.
В принципе у меня почти получилось, но меню до верха не достаёт 65px.
Как сделать так чтобы фон меню был на всю высоту экрана, а пункты второстепенного меню остались напротив родительского меню?

сейчас меню выглядит так

[image: сейчас меню выглядит так]

должно быть так

[image: должно быть так]

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5263/178988

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой вариант (при котором не надо менять остальной код) - это сделать тень наверх.

Другой вариант - разместить фон в псевдоэлементе, который и расположить на всю высоту.

PS: 100vh уходит вниз за экран - это может быть нехорошо.

Вот реализация с псевдоэлементом:

```css
html, body, nav {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  color: white;
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 8em;
}

ul::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: -100vh;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, black, #555);
}

li ul {
  margin: -1.5em 0 0 8em;
  display: none;
}

li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}

a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li:hover > a {
  background: silver;
}

a:not(:last-child)::before {
  content: "►";
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a>First</a>
    <li><a>Second</a>
    <li><a>Nested</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>Nested 1</a>
        <li><a>Nested 2</a>
        <li><a>Nested again</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a>Inermost 1</a>
            <li><a>Inermost 2</a>
            <li><a>Inermost 3</a>
            <li><a>Inermost 4</a>
          </ul>
        <li><a>Nested 4</a>
      </ul>
    <li><a>Fourth</a>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Да, с тенью всё получилось, спасибо. Но я так понимаю, что тень задаётся в конкретных пикселях и сейчас я смогу это значение прописать исходя из положения первого основного пункта меню. Но если будут еще пункты ниже, то и второстепенное меню вместе с короткой тенью будет перемещаться вниз. Можно в параметрах меню выставить какое-то очень большое значение, чтобы тень уходила вверх за экран? Или это тоже может быть нехорошо?

Comment: @ИгорьЛешок, вместо пикселей можно указать те же 100vh. Вниз может быть нехорошо по двум причинам - меню в экран не влезет, либо где-то вылезет скролл даже если меню в экран влезет. С тенью такой проблемы не будет. Но я бы всё же воспользовался вариантом с псевдоэлементом.

Comment: Мне тоже идея с псевдоэлементом больше понравилась. Тень - это всё-таки костыль. Как это сделать?

Comment: Про тень (правда, ты коммент уже удалил) - на элемент с высотой 100vh повесить `box-shadow: 0 -100vh #2e2f33;`. Про псевдоэлемент - сейчас сделаю.

Comment: Да, я про минус забыл

Comment: @ИгорьЛешок, я сделал, но всё равно получилось немного не так, как я думал и пришлось класть в блок с overflow:hidden, а значит, если меню в экран не влезло, оно обрезается :(

Comment: @ИгорьЛешок, ну что?

Comment: Если честно, то я обратился к фрилансеру, и мне всё сделали. Вкратце вот что сделали: в папке шаблона добавил стили style.txt в файл style.css, добавил скрипт footer.txt в конец footer.php

Comment: Но ваша подсказка с тенью на время закрыла брешь, поэтому вам спасибо! В варианте с псевдоэлементом я просто не разобрался. Слишком сложно для меня.